# How do you use sorted-map-by to sort a map by value?

Tags: clojure

I cant understand the documentation at all.

I want a sorted map "xxx", which sorts the map according to the value. How do I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: As explained by @sepp2k, this is not generally possible with Clojure core’s sorted maps – their order is based on _key_ sort order. Check out [clojure.data.priority-map](https://github.com/clojure/data.priority-map) for an abstraction that does support this.

Answer (score 18):

Another way is to compare the values from the original map within the comparer function.

```
(def my-map {:chad 3 :bob 5 :sammy 4})

;; sort by keys ascending
(into (sorted-map) my-map)
=> {:bob 5, :chad 3, :sammy 4}

;; sort by values ascending
(into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2] (compare (key1 my-map) (key2 my-map)))) my-map)
=> {:chad 3, :sammy 4,  :bob 5}

;; sort by values descending
(into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2] (compare (key2 my-map) (key1 my-map)))) my-map)
=> {:bob 5, :sammy 4, :chad 3}
```

Comment: Beware, there is a bug in your solution, check this:
(def my-map {:chad 3 :bob 5 :alice 3 :sammy 4})

With your solution, :alice 3 will be cut off from the resulting map.

Comment: @AlfredoDiNapoli I noticed the same problem. I was able to fix it, using <= instead of compare in the anonymous function.

Comment: Isn't @Rafael idea of using `<=` instead of `compare` binding my code to implementation of `sorted-map-by`?

Clojure Docs refers to that use case of `sorted-map-by` and proposes such solution:
`(into (sorted-map-by (fn [key1 key2] (compare [(key1 my-map2) key1] [(key2 my-map2) key2]))) my-map2)` instead

Answer (score 6):

You use sorted-map-by by specifying a comparisson followed by the key-value-pairs. The comparator is a function which takes two keys and returns -1, 0 or 1 depending on whether the first key is smaller than, equal to or greater than the second key.

Example:

```
user=> (sorted-map-by (fn [k1 k2] (compare (mod k1 10) (mod k2 10))) 10 1 23 4 2 5)
{10 1, 2 5, 23 4}
```

Since the comparisson function only takes keys as arguments, you can't use this to sort by the values.

There is no way to have a sorted map where the map is sorted by the values. If it were, it wouldn't be possible to find an entry by key because you could not use the order to determine where the entry is (since the order would not depend on the key).

Comment: In the doc page i think you can read the converse meaning "If you wish to sort the map according to the values,..." http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/sorted-map-by