# clojure sort always return a list

Tags: clojure

To sort a vector in clojure

```
(sort [ 2 3 1 4])
```

returns a list (sorted)

```
(1 2 3 4)
```

I can turn it back into the vector by

```
(into [] (sort [ 2 3 1 4]))
```

which is kind of inconvenient.

But if I sort a map/dictionary in clojure

```
(sort {2 "" 3 "" 1 "" 4 ""})
```

the return

```
([1 ""] [2 ""] [3 ""] [4 ""])
```

How do I turn it back into a sorted map? Or is there a better sort function that keeps the type/shape of the input?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528632/how-do-you-use-sorted-map-by-in-clojure

Comment: not a dupe, but http://stackoverflow.com/q/1989301/599075 indicates that there isn't a great way

Comment: I was about to post an answer involving [`empty`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty) and [`into`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into), but it turned out to be much less useful than I expected.

Comment: Perhaps something like `(apply into ((juxt empty sort) coll))`, doesn't seem very useful though.

Comment: btw, `sort` doesn't return a list, but an ArraySeq.  `(class (sort [2 3 1 4])) ;=>
clojure.lang.ArraySeq`, vs `(class '(4 3 2 1)) ;=> clojure.lang.PersistentList`.  Clojure has lots of different collection data structures, but there are only a few collection delimiter characters available, so there are things that aren't lists but whose printed representations use parentheses.  There are not many functions that return lists, I believe.  `list` is an exception. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I dont know of a general way to always keep the original type/shape.

In case of a sorted map, its important to know that a regular map in clojure has no order (at least nothing you can or should rely on). For that clojure has `sorted-map`. There is also a useful function [`sorted-map-by`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-map-by) that allows you to specify your own ordering.

So, in your example:

```
(into (sorted-map)  {2 "" 3 "" 1 "" 4 ""})
;; {1 "", 2 "", 3 "", 4 ""}
```